64-pin chips in the 1980s
Imagine that in the year 198x I decided to develop a 68000 computer. Unfortunately, I realised that my chipset must include a couple of 64-pin chips.
What would be the consequences for me in terms of manufacturing feasibility, expenses etc. in every year between 1981 and 1987?
I notice that the Amiga OCS, for example, was implemented with 48-pin chips. Were 64-pins too expensive then, or not available at all?

TMS-9900 introduced in 1976 already used a 64 pin DIP socket. I don't think it was the price of the socket that made the TI-99/4 fail in 1983.

DEC's J-11 was a PDP-11 on a DIP - note that the DIP had 60 pins - but the DIP also held two ceramic leadless packages that look like they have a LOT more pins each - so ... doable?  User guide for it is dated 1983 for "preliminary".

Plenty around when they were needed. Such as TRW’s TDC1010 16x16 multiplier-accumulator chip, Page 260 of this PDF. 64 pins, bipolar, 5W dissipation made it too hot to touch. But the fact that it had only 64 pins when it really needed 68 may be an argument for a technological limit: just at a higher size than you suggest.

I remember reading somewhere (but not exactly where, or I'd be posting an answer) that the big problem with high-pin-count ICs was the lack of suitable test equipment to qualify them (I don't know whether that's on-wafer test or after packaging - or both).

Classic 8-bitters like 68HC11 from 1984 came in PLCC-52. And this was a low end, cost-optimized product. For something similar to 68k you would have more of a budget and picking a larger PLCC up to 84 pins wouldn't be a problem. Check out for example Intel 80286 which would be a direct competitor with 68k at the time.

@Lundin thank you! that's the answer I've been looking for!

64-pin DIPs were available in the 80s: the Motorola 68000, introduced in 1979, came in a 64-pin DIP. When it was designed, this was pushing the envelope; quoting the Computer History Museum’s Oral History Panel on the Development and Promotion of the Motorola 68000:

House: So what decisions did you later decide that maybe you could have made differently?
Gunter: […] I don't know what we would've done differently, but the packaging for the 68000 was in a 64–pin, large, heavy–cost package. And 64 pins at the time were just terrible. Then we knew, we got from some of the later customers, we had to get that into plastic. I affectionately named what turned out to be the 64–pin plastic package as the “Texas Cockroach,” a great big thing. It was about the size of a Hershey Bar, but with a lot of legs. And it was about as ugly as a Hershey Bar with a lot of legs. It took us forever to get that thing right, in spite of all of your prowess in manufacturing, because it would bow and twist and crack the die. It's hard to say what it didn't do. You just couldn't afford to keep paying over $75.00 for ceramic
packages from KSN.
House: I remember the very, very large package, with lots of pins.
Gunter: I don't know how many times I got lectures on it: “If you had to go to a large package, why didn't you go to 48 instead of all the way to 64?” But we decided not to multiplex any of the addresses. But I'm not sorry we did it the way we did it. It was very important to have that linear address space the way we addressed it because that allowed us to use almost any type of static RAM, ROMs at the time; eventually the EPROM system. It's very easy to attach the 68000s to memories, because it had all the timing pretty much built in, and we needed the link. So those were the right things, the DM. The things that were not so right: we should have gone earlier to a CMOS implementation, some manufacturing stream issues. Not that we weren't getting the recommendations, we just—

So it was difficult, at least in the late 70s, and expensive; probably only worth it in the 68000 because it avoided multiplexing address lines. That might not be justifiable on a support chip like those in the Amiga OCS (which was designed for use with the 68000).
Carriers other than DIPs make it easier to provide more pins; PLCCs in particular were popular in the late 80s, but they were only standardised in 1984, and PGAs of course but mostly for CPUs, at least initially. See this collection of 80s PC motherboards for pictorial examples of the evolution in carrier use.

Thank you! I guess I need to find what were the first popular plcc84 chips to get the idea when this packaging became affordable...

Fat Agnus is one example but there are probably earlier uses (perhaps for PC chipsets).

Fat Agnus was featured on 5rev motherboard of a500, but it's hard to figure out when it was released :(

I was fully expecting issues to be around routing traces etc. by hand for so many lines, not issues with packaging itself!

@MattLacey Routing was the killer issue for PGAs in the days of THT since it's super hard to get to the inner pins. DIP is comparably easy to route regardless of pin count, as long as the pinout is sane enough so that pins belonging to the same bus are next to each other and not scattered all around the package.

Any idea who KSN might be?

This sounds like a tour thru all kind of packaging, doesn't it?
TL;DR: Use PLCC
It all depends on your supplier. MOS used DIP 48 as they had machinery for DIP that could be adapted to 48 pin. After al, the most restricting part in selecting a package is what your chip manufacturer can provide. Other than MOS could have been more flexible.

If your manufacturer is without that restriction, the most simple and most flexible packaging at that time (1980s) would be PLCC. Very common across various manufacturers since the 1980s, way more compact than DIP, can be used with sockets in THT and without with SMT (or as well using SMT sockets). WDC's W65C02S is maybe a good example of DIP vs. PLCC vs QFN. Further the Apple IIgs Motherboard makes a great contemporary (1986) example how  THT DIP would be mixed with PLCC with or without socket and leaded QFP, all in one board.
For more technical details see this page and this page provided by two PCB manufacturers. They are of course written from today's usage, but the basic features haven't changed much (ignore the finer pitch variants).

The Long Read

What would be the consequences for me in terms of manufacturing feasibility,

#1 Step: Ask your supplier.
No doubt the most important part. Back in the 70s and 80s packaging was for the majority of chip manufacturer still an inhouse job. That is, they would only do types of packaging they had the machinery for.
That restriction of available production was, beside space concerns, one reason that Intel's implementation of the Datapoint design used DIP 18, while TI's TMX 1795 used the wider DIP 24. Similar goes for the 8086. By staying with 40 pin, cheaper packaging could be used with all customer side cost being similar to 8085 designs.

expenses

Of of course different packaging may incur with different cost - again related to the manufacturers setup. Choosing a rare packaging type means more competition about the packaging line, thus higher price point - but that's of course negotiable - mostly depending on volume.

e.t.c. for every X between 1 and 7?

Using the same (unusual) packaging for multiple chips doesn't add issues - in fact, it may lower cost if they all use the same packaging.

I guess 64pins were too expensive? Or unavailable at all?

Not really and see above. I'ts all about having (or investing in) the machinery to package those larger chips.
But Boards?
Beside looking at the chip, boards design also adds requirements. While the die may not increase much related to pins supported, the package does so linear if the packaging doesn't change. That's why a DIP64 like an 68000 in 2.54 mm (100 mil) spacing requires not only adds a good 30 mm in length compared to a 40 pin (81 vs. 51mm) but also 33% in width (800 instead of 600 mil). So for 60% more pins (+24), the space requirement is increased by 130% (800 mm2 -> 1850 mm2), that's more than doubled.
Maybe less of an issue if you're just building some prototype or one off unit, but a true killer for mass production. One might get away if it's just one of those oversized, like the CPU, but not with many. While Motorola offered several support chips as 48..64 pin DIP, customers usually picked he pin-grid variant for space(*1).
Common Types of High Pin-Count Packaging in the 1980s
A wide variety of chip packaging were available during the 1980s, exploring different ways, much like today.
DIP - Dual Inline Package
There are other variants beside the well known 2.54 mm DIP.
2.54 mm (100 mil) DIP
That's the standard 2.54 mm spaced DIP, like used by the 68k and most 8 bit systems. Almost perfect for anything up to 300 mil 24 pin. Acceptable for 600 mil up to DIP 40. At least in the mid 1980s (and low cost). 64 pin was available as early as 1978, so already dated for your 198x project :)
2mm DIP
A 2 mm spaced DIP can fit 48 pin in the same space as a 40 pin 2.54mm. A 64 pin will save compared to  2.54, but still take ~65mm in length. Used by some Japanese manufacturers in the 1980s to early 1990s.
1.78mm (70 mil) DIP
The smallest commonly used DIP reduces the pin distance to 1.78mm. Now a 64 pin ends up at 58mm, less than 7 mm larger than a 40 pin in 2.54mm. For all manufacturing purpose mostly equivalent. Notable chips using this spacing were Hitachi's 64180 (aka Zilog Z180) and Yamaha's VDP 9958. Bothe are middle of the road of your time frame (1985 and 1988).
QIP - Quad Inline Package
QIP, today often ignored, is a very interesting packaging and the earliest form of high density. In fact, QIP is older than DIP, being used by some of the very first integrated circuits made for mainframes in the 1960s (*2) as well as in micro processors like Rockwell's PPS-4 as early as 1973. So pretty much well proven and standard during the 1980s.
QIP could package a 44 pin in the same 'length' as a 20 pin DIP - at the cost of doubling its width to 1200 mil (*3). Still way more space saving than doing the same in DIP. This was reached by spacing pins at 50 mil (half standard DIP) and staggering them by 90 mil. Rockwell's beautiful R6511Q (*4) packaged a 64 pinout in 41 by 23.5 mm2, that's barely 3mm wider than a 600 mil DIP 40 but a whole 10 mm shorter.
The packaging was long established and widely used by Rockwell, Motorola, Sharp, Zilog and many others - especially when space was a premium. So finding a manufacturer for your chips would not be stopped by selecting QIP.
QUIP - Quad Unleaded Inline Package
QUIP was developed by intel to handle the higher pincount of their upcoming super chip iAPX432. QUIP stripped the pins for a series of pads and can be seen as a direct predecessor to later Leadless Chip Carrier (LCC).
xLLC -  Leadless Chip Carrier
Various forms of LCC appeard during the 1980s LLC. Notably Intel's 80186, 80286. Other manufacturer, like Motorola went for CLCC. and so on. All of those carry a one major disadvantage as they all need sockets to be put on a PCB.Something that can be justified for a main CPU - especially if in need of a head spreader anyway, but otherwise not great for large scale production runs.
PLCC - Plastic Leadless Chip Carrier
PLCC is the exception here - and in some way not really an LLC, as it still features pins. Just here they are bend inward under the carrier. That way it's dual use, all the advantage of a finer pitch (1.27 mm /50 mil) and pins along all sides, usable in a socket and can be direct soldered. Except, no longer being a thru-hole but SMD.
Kind of an all-in-one solution (*5) and a great bridge technology used by many 1980's manufacturers. The Apple IIgs Motherboard is a great example of mixing THT DIP with PLCC in socket and soldered and leaded QFP, all on he same board 1986.
Time wise it fits the whole 1980s, as PLCC was developed by TI in the mid 1970s with first PLCC as we now know today (post-mold *6) delivered in 1976. By 1980 many others had joined. Not at least because of post-mold PLCC being the cheapest way for high pincount packages. By 1981 JEDEC took PLCC for standardisation which produced a norm in 1984. At that time most major manufacturer already added PLCC to their portfolio.
SOP and QFP
Both are SMT packages either DIL style with two rows (SOP) or four on all sides (QFP). Commonality is a way finer pitch, starting at 1.25 mm (50 mil) with the earliest generations and shrinking to 1 mm, 0.7 mm, 0.5 mm and nowadays sometimes below that. For mid 1980s only 1.27 mm and 1 mm might be applicable.
Of course, like with xLLC, one needs to find a manufacturer supplying those packages.
PGA - Pin Grid Array
Beside going SMT there was also an option using Pin Grid Array (PGA). those can be seen as an attempt to continue with the advantages of using THT while being able to increasing pin density beyond one or two rows along all sides. It was used with many designs, most notably micro processors all the way to Pentium class chips (*7). Much like LCC they were restricted to high end chip. also, they only solved the pin issue, but added cost for board design when going past on row around all sides.
Where QFP grows in size with pin numbers along the sides and requires more board space, the additional board space also relaxes routing. With dense PGA, it gets harder and harder to bring the inner pins out, usually needing ever more connection layers - which significantly increases production cost. Such chips were usually only seen on high end boards. This cost is why high end PC-type CPUs like 386, 486 or 68k often used (socketed) PGA, their embedded and customer class cousins weer mostly QFP. Trading layers for space use helps saving cost.

*1 - The 48 pin 68901 being the exception to prove the rule - but that's mostly due the sheer size of Atari ST being sold worldwide :))
*2 - When IBM developed SLT and MLT for their new /360, competition like RCA or Siemens directly went for ICs using QIP. Where SLT had an early advantage in miniaturization, by making each component in itself smaller, using ICs proved to scale better by just throwing ever more, but way smaller, components at the same task. Who cares that an IC needs 7 transistors to do the same as a one transistor and two resistors if the first can be all packaged into a single IC? Sounds kinda well known, doesn't it?
*3 - Using only mil mil here since the most common examples are by US companies, designed in the 1960s/70s using imperial. For stuff that old conversion to modern units makes less sense.
*4 - The R6511Q is the NMOS (!) chip that first premiered what later became known as CMOS-Extension.
*5 - Known in Bavaria as Eierlegende Wollmilchsau.
*6 - Post-Mold means the chip gets first put on its carrier (where the pins are), bonded and then engulfed with a plastic housing. same way as common plastic TTL. Just smaller thus at lower cost. Original PLCC used a pre-mold process, where the carrier is already embedded in plastic and bonding happens with it, which needs more careful operation and different machinery. Post-Mold greatly simplified it.
*7 - And rediscovered after the excursion into slot CPU types.

And we should not forget about industrial equipment for chip testing.
Installations for 64 pins were noticeably more expensive and appeared later.

In case anyone is curious, the Star Gemini 10x printer included a QIP.

Thank you! I think what I've learned from your comment is more than I knew about chip packaging at all!

Realistically at what year could I start manufacturing a plcc84 that would be reasonably priced for a home computer?

@Anton Added a history section to PLCC. PLCC as today (with 1.27 mm spacing) is used by TI since 1976, standardized 1984. Not sure about 84 pin, but 68 pin would work at scale as early as 1980. ofc, prices are dropping more over time. However with sufficient venture money, and high hopes to sell a large number, any year in the early 1980s can work. Past 1984 PLCC becomes almost a must if you do your own chips.

@Raffzahn thank you! Exactly what I was hoping for!

@supercat - as did the Epson LX800. I think it was a Hitachi microcontroller that used a QIP

@scruss: I wonder how the price of a microcontroller compared with the price of a 6502, ROM, and some latches and other discrete logic (I think micros with as much RAM as the SG10x had would have been rather pricey).  I think even a 1MHz 6502 would have plenty of horsepower to drive a 120cps 9-pin printer with an output data rate of 1,440 nonets/second.

@supercat - probably. I have a vague memory of the QIP chip inside the Epson being a Z80 derivative

The problem isn't just the DIP package but the fact that you can only miniaturize the bonding lands so much. A chip with 16 bonding lands per edge instead of 10 has 2.56 times the area. And about three times the cost per chip due to more waste at the edge of the wafer.
You have to make good use of all that extra space to justify that much higher cost.

Bonding lands could be staggered in two or sometimes even three rows, but it had cost area either way. It just would not be a quadratic growth relative to number of pins, but slightly slower as the number of staggered rows increased. It made wire bonding a pain though, so it was not a preferred solution for many.
